# call-template returns "Supplied element name is a zero-length string"

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am preparing to modularize my code since I need to build a XHTML doc about 2000 lines of code. If I run the "value-of" directly in the last template I get out the correct result. It fails when running "call-template".

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{
  "main": {
    "head-content": "myTitle2",
    "body-content": {
      "Pencils": 43
    }
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <!-- Block all data that has no user defined template -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Module: Body content -->

  <xsl:template name="body" match="*[@key='body-content']//*[@key and not(*)]">
      <xsl:element name="{@key}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Module: Head content -->

  <xsl:template name="head" match="*[@key='head']//*[@key and not(*)]">
      <xsl:element name="{@key}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="*:map[not(@key)]">
   <head>
     <title>
       <!-- Works -->
       <!-- <xsl:value-of select="//*[@key='head-content']"/> -->
       <!-- Does not work -->
       <xsl:call-template name="head"/>
   </title>
 </head>
   <body>
     <!-- Works -->
     <!-- <xsl:value-of select="//*[@key='body-content']"/> -->
     <!-- Does not work -->
       <xsl:call-template name="body"/>
   </body>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**
Blank, with errror:

```
Error on line 27 column 34 of principal.xsl: XTDE0820 Supplied element name is a zero-length string
```

**Wanted result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<head>
   <title>myTitle2</title>
</head>
<body>43</body>
```

Comment: `call-template` does not change the context node thus if you have match on an element without a `key` attribute it doesn't make sense to use `call-template` for a template that tries to output some value from the `key` attribute. I think you will be much better off if you embrace apply-templates and push based XSLT processing.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks!. I will give a try to learn more about the apply-templates concept.